# Collect Form Data, insert in xml fields to post to Payment Gateway

Tags: php, xml

I need to take payment information from a form and place it in XML and then post it to the payment gateway server. I am rather a novice at best and I am not sure of the easiest way to do this.

I have successfully been able to post to the payment gateway by manually entering the info into the XML on a static php file, so I know the XML is correct, the only real issue for me would be finding the easiest way to take form data and place into the XML.

Below is a sample of the php file and the XML.

```
<?php 
$TransactionId = intval( date(Yms). rand(1,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9) . rand(0,9). rand(0,9) );

$MerchantId="111111";
$TerminalId="111111";
$ApiPassword="111111";
$private_key="asdfasghgfdhggdfgs";
$ApiPassword_encrypt=hash('sha256',$ApiPassword);   

$xmlReq='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TransactionRequest xmlns="https://test.processing.com/securePayments/direct/v1/processor.php">
<Language>ENG</Language>
<Credentials>
<MerchantId>'.$MerchantId.'</MerchantId>
<TerminalId>'.$TerminalId.'</TerminalId>
<TerminalPassword>'.$ApiPassword_encrypt.'</TerminalPassword>
</Credentials>
<TransactionType>LP001</TransactionType>
<TransactionId>'.$TransactionId.'</TransactionId>
<ReturnUrl page="http://www.website.net/response.php">
<Param>
<Key>inv</Key>
<Value>'.$TransactionId.'</Value>
</Param>        
</ReturnUrl>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<TotalAmount>44450</TotalAmount>

<CardDetails>
<CardHolderName>John Smith</CardHolderName>
<CardNumber>4653111111111111</CardNumber>
<CardExpireMonth>01</CardExpireMonth>
<CardExpireYear>15</CardExpireYear>
<CardType>VI</CardType>
<CardSecurityCode>030</CardSecurityCode>
<CardIssuingBank>UNKNOWN</CardIssuingBank>
<CardIssueNumber></CardIssueNumber>
</CardDetails>
</TransactionRequest>';

$signature_key=trim($private_key.$ApiPassword.$TransactionId);
$signature=base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", trim($xmlReq), $signature_key, True));
$encodedMessage=base64_encode($xmlReq);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markup your static xml with some sort of placeholder like `{{key}}`. then use this function to fill your xml:

```
<?php
function fill_template($tpl, $values = array()) {
    $find = array();
    preg_match_all("/\\{\\{([^}]+)\\}\\}/", $tpl, &$find);

    foreach ($find[1] as $x => $key) {
        $repl = '';
        if (isset($values[$key])) {
            $repl = $values[$key];
        }
        $tpl = str_replace($find[0][$x], $repl);
    }

    return $tpl;
}
?>
```

the `$values` parameter should contain the values from `$_POST`, along with whatever other values you need to set:

```
<?php
$payment_map = array('MerchantId' => 'xxx', 'TerminalId' => 'xxx');
$payment_map = array_merge($payment_map, $_POST);
$xml_template = "your markedup xml";
$xml = fill_template($xml_template, $payment_map);
?>
```

this may not be the most elegant solution but it should get you moving.

(obviously you'll want to validate form data and encode it into proper xml characters if necessary.)